# “ImportError: Couldn't import Django.” even after having Django in Virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I am trying to run an old project of django but i am getting error like couldn't import Django. i already activated my virtualenv.

> (venv) shivam@shivam-Inspiron-3542:~/grappus-olx/grappus-olx/src$
> python3 manage.py runserver

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

[image: Folder Image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure you activate the right virtual environment. if you have django installed on the virtual environment you can see the version by `django-admin --version` if you don't means that django is not installed

Comment: its says Django command not found.Please see the image i attached with the question.Thank You

Comment: what happen when you run this command? pip install django-admin

Comment: It installed successfully.But Still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you had created a `requirements.txt` file for you old project, run the `pip install -r requirements.txt` and it will install Django based on the version you had used.

If you don't have a `requirements.txt` file, run the `pip freeze` command within your virtual environment to confirm if Django is on the list of installed packages.

Comment: i dont have requirements.txt file but i can  see Django with its version in after executing pip freeze command.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be something went wrong while installation i.e misconfiguration occured
so just uninstall django by running  `pip uninstall django`

Then install different version of django like `pip install django==3.0.3`

then check if it works. If it works then install latest version by typing `pip install django==3.0.8`

Comment: i uninstalled django 1.11.29 from venv and when i was trying to install 3.0.3 it said "could not find a version that satisfy the requirement django==3.0.3"

Comment: after uninstalling django i can still able to see the django folder in the site package of venv.

Comment: So install a version of Django other than the version you are using

Comment: still django --version command not found.Thanks for help